# How to use OpenAPI generator with corporate proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, openapi-generator

I am trying to use [OpenAPI generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to automatically generate C# client code based on a `openapi: "3.0.2"` json configuration:

```
openapi-generator generate -i https://test.com/docs/swagger/openapi.json -g csharp-netcore -c open-api-config.json -o DataLakeOpenApiRestClient.cs
```

This fails with the following error:

> [main] ERROR io.swagger.v3.parser.util.RemoteUrl - unable to read
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.RemoteUrl.urlToString(RemoteUrl.java:147)
>           at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readWithInfo(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:123)
>           at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:45)
>           at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
>           at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:586)
>           at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:395)
>           at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator.main(OpenAPIGenerator.java:60)

However if I download the json file and run using a local file input, it works fine:

```
openapi-generator generate -i open-api-offline-file.json -g csharp-netcore -c open-api-config.json -o DataLakeOpenApiRestClient.cs
```

I have tested this on a computer without a corporate proxy and it works properly, so my main suspect is the proxy.

I have set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY, but they are not used.

**Question:** How to use OpenAPI generator with corporate proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the networking properties using `-D`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

e.g.

```
openapi-generator generate -i open-api-offline-file.json -g csharp-netcore -c open-api-config.json -o DataLakeOpenApiRestClient.cs -Dhttps.proxyHost=internal-proxy.mycompany.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work although it makes sense. I have also tried with `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true`. I am wondering if `openapi-generator` actually reads these options. Anyway, I think I can get the content via another command and use the offline generation.

Comment: These options are (or should be) used by Swagger Parser (a dependency of OpenAI Generator) when parsing the OpenAPI/Swagger doc/spec.

Comment: `[DEPRECATED] -D arguments after 'generate' are application arguments and not Java System Properties, please consider changing to -p, or apply your options to JAVA_OPTS, or move the -D arguments before the jar option.`